# Count in a multiple join statement

Tags: mysql, join, left-join

I have three tables **Post:** `int id, varchar title`
**Comment:**`int comment_id, int post_id, varchar comment` **Likes:** `int like_id, int post_id` 
Here post_id is a foreign key references table *post*.

I'm trying to get all the posts along with the count of comments and count of likes made on each post.

Here is what I have done so far:

```
    SELECT post.id, post.title, count(comment.id) as comments,

    FROM post

    left join comment on comment.post_id = post.id

    GROUP by post.id
```

This gives me the result for all the posts and count of comments made of each post. Now as soon as I add the next left join for likes table the count result return twice of it's actual value.

E.g If a post X had 2 comments and I add the *like* table join the count for the same post start giving me 4 as total count of comment on post X.

Help appreciated.

Comment: Just use `COUNT(DISTINCT comment.id)`

Comment: @Nick It worked. Can you please explain the work done behind the scene which I was unable to follow-up.

Comment: When you add the second `JOIN` to the `likes` table, any post that has multiple comments and multiple likes will end up with the product of the two numbers rows in the output, with values from each table replicated according to the number of rows in the other table (e.g. 2 likes and 3 comments => 6 rows, so each like id will be copied 3 times and each comment id will be copied twice). By using `DISTINCT` you can factor out that duplication to only get the unique comments or likes.

Comment: Yes, perfect this make sense. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would write this using two separate subqueries to find the count of the comments and likes:

```
SELECT
    p.id,
    p.title,
    COALESCE(c.comment_cnt, 0) AS comments,
    COALESCE(l.like_cnt, 0) AS likes
FROM post p
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT post_id, COUNT(*) AS comment_cnt
    FROM comments
    GROUP BY post_id
) c
    ON p.id = c.post_id
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT post_id, COUNT(*) AS like_cnt
    FROM likes
    GROUP BY post_id
) l
    ON p.id = l.post_id;
```

Comment: This solution also works for me, but if we talk on a optimised query point of view, isn't your query slow compare to the one I have? I mean I see two joins and two sub-queries on top of a query.

Comment: Not really, no, because those `DISTINCT` operations are probably just as costly as what I wrote.  I prefer my answer because it is clear what is being done, and there is no "magic" happening.

Comment: Honestly I still think that join and `DISTINCT` are much optimised than sub-query. Anyways thanks to your solution I know how `COALESCE` work.
Thanks for the help mate.

Comment: If you are really concerned, then check the explain plan of both queries.  The distinct approach would result in a potentially very large intermediate table which MySQL would then have to aggregate down.

Comment: I agree with Tim in all aspects here. First, we want to show the posts with their comments counts and their likes counts, so we join comments counts and likes counts to the posts. Second, producing a cartesian product only to use `COUNT(DISTINCT)` to muddle through this data mess can get very costly.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner In case of Tim answer adding explain to the query shows that only one possible key/keys is present which is the derived one from sub-query. The number of rows are also higher in explain's result for Tim's answer since we have two additional sub-queries. The only upside I can see is that _select type_ under explain query has 3 PRIMARY for Tim's answer and with DISTINCT its for 1 row only.
Though your argument is also making so much sense.

Comment: @Deepak Singh: As long as the database is small, it's no big deal to join a post's comments with all its likes and thus produce a cartesian product. But once it gets bigger, you can run into grave performance issues. If there were 10,000 posts (still no big database), each with 20 comments and 10 likes, then Tim's query would deal with a maximum number of 200,000 rows (the comments) and could even get their aggregation result by reading the index only, which means very little disk access. The `COUNT DISTINCT` query on the other hand would produce 20 million rows which must then get aggregated.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Yes, indeed you have a fair point. As of now I have a small db and also I'm using limit while fetching the posts but your explanation still make me wonder if I should change my query with Tim's. Thanks for the time and explanation mate.